# Upload module to CPAN without using pause.perl.org

Tags: perl

Since a few days pause.perl.org service is down.
Is there a way to upload modules to CPAN without using pause.perl.org ?

Comment: Here's some info about this stuff: http://log.perl.org/2014/01/multiple-hard-drive-faliure.html (found at http://blogs.perl.org/users/ivan_bessarabov/2014/01/pausecpanorg-is-not-working-does-somebody-know-something.html)

Comment: And as far as I know PAUSE is the only way to upload stuff to CPAN.

Comment: I'm full agree Computer crashes can not be excluded, 
but in worst case there should be possible to manage modules.
To have a backup plan for worst case szenario is a must for every assurance and support team of the world. 
Especially for such an important and big environment like CPAN

Comment: It looks like nobody is perfect. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. I suppose theoretically you could bug the sys admins of some of the higher tier CPAN mirrors, and request they add your tarball manually. But in that case your module wouldn't get indexed correctly, etc. So we just have to wait.

In the mean time, I'd suggest uploading elsewhere, such as your personal web server, or Google Code, etc. People installing using cpanminus should be able to do so just using the URL for the tarball:

```
cpanm 'http://example.com/~ovntatar/perl/Foo-Bar-1.001.tar.gz'
```

If it's an especially important release (e.g. contains a vital bug fix) then announcing the release on blogs.perl.org, PerlMonks, or a relevant irc.perl.org channel would bee a good idea.

When PAUSE reappears, you can re-upload the same tarball there.